# how can I do this rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an url address like: `example.com/?page=3`

How can I write the .htaccess rewrite rule, to redirect such pages to `example.com/pageid/3`

Here "3" is just an example. I would like to make this redirect with any given number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /pageid/%2  [L]
```

Replace the `[L]` with `[L,R]` if you want to redirect the browser, thus changing what's in the address bar to `example.com/pageid/3` instead of redirecting internally.